# How do i count the number of values in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, iteration

Nothing fancy or complex, I just want to know how to count the amount of values that are in a dictionary and how to implement it into a for loop. I've scowered far and wide but no one can seem to tell me this. Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
parc = {"Parcel": 10. "Parcel2": 5, "Parcel13": 4}
for i in len(parc):
    print("Parcel" + str(i))
```

Comment: "values" or "keys"? Also please paste the actual code and not images of code.

Comment: Do you want the count of values or the size it's been holding?

Comment: The code (which should be included as formatted text , not a screenshot) does not illustrate the expected output

Comment: @user3471881 when will those be different?  speaking of which, won't those always evaluate to the same as `len(dictionary)` anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are looking for this:

```
parc = {"Parcel": 10, "Parcel2": 5 , "Parcel3": 4}
print(len(parc.keys()))
```

Output:

```
3
```